# Firebase Remote Config getInt() missing

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Firebase provides the following methods:

- getBoolean()
- getByteArray()
- getDouble()
- getLong()
- getString()

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#get-parametervalues-to-use-in-your-app

But getInt() is missing from this list, I'm curious if there's a reason for this? Is the preferred approach to use Long or String and cast/convert to an int?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [iOS has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335850/how-to-get-integer-value-from-firebase-remote-config-in-ios-swift), oddly enough.

Since `int` is a subset of `long`, you should use this to store your integer.