# how to get integer value from Firebase Remote Config in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

so I set Firebase remote config default in my iOS like this:

```
let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

// set remote config default value
let defaultRemoteConfig : [String:NSObject] = [
  "number_of_recommended_events_to_show_per_page" : 15 as NSObject
]

remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultRemoteConfig)

 // Activate and refetch remote config data. 
 // I use 'Load Value for next time' loading strategy
 remoteConfig.activate()
 remoteConfig.fetch()
```

and then I want to get the value from remote like this

```
 // get the value from remote config
let numberOfDocumentsPerQuery = remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "number_of_recommended_events_to_show_per_page").numberValue as! Int
```

I need the value in Integer format, but it crash when I cast it to `Int` like that 
[image]

here is how I set the value in the console
[image]

why is it nil ? how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you `fetchAndActivate` your config before trying to access a value? And don't use force unwrap `!` operator.

Comment: @mag_zbc yes, I fetch it before trying to get the value. I have edited my question. yup, it is better to avoid exclamation mark but just to make my problem clearer

Comment: Probably the rempote config has not been fetched yet... As far as I remember it's an asynch procedure. Use the fetch with completionHandler.

Comment: @Alexa289: you are welcome! I used the remote config more than one year ago for a big app I've worked on and I had the same problem. I do not remember the logic of the default values sorry.
The crash is because you unwrapped the Optional without the control... NEVER do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've fetched in this block before getting a remote value.

```
func fetchCloudValues() {
  // WARNING: Don't actually do this in production!
  let fetchDuration: TimeInterval = 0

  RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: fetchDuration) { [weak self] status, error in

    if let error = error {
      print ("Uh-oh. Got an error fetching remote values \(error)")
      return
    }

    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activateFetched()
    print ("Retrieved values from the cloud!")
    let numberOfEvents = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
                                            .configValue(forKey: "number_of_recommended_events_to_show_per_page")
                                            .intValue ?? 0
    print("Our app's number of events is \(numberOfEvents)")

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> try this!

```
let numberOfDocumentsPerQuery = remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "number_of_recommended_events_to_show_per_page").numberValue?.intValue ?? 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Other answers didn't quite work for me. However the following did...

```
let numberOfDocumentsPerQuery = remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "number_of_recommended_events_to_show_per_page").numberValue.intValue
```